# How to fetch the first key from list using robot framework code?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, robotframework

I am trying to fetch the 1st key value from a list. But I am getting the entire list values.

I have tried robot framework code

```
  "details":[{"name": "john","id": "1","add": "usa"}]

   Robottest.robot->
     @{det}=    Set Variable     ${['details']}
     ${type_ABC}=     Evaluate    type(@{det})
     log to console  ${type_ABC} - ##Prints TYPE <List>
     :FOR    ${item}     IN      @{det}
           log to console ${item}   #Prints {u'name': john', u'id': u'1'}
           ${dict}=   Get From List       ${det}         0
           log to console     ${dict} - dict  #Expected "name":"john" but it is printing all id and add as well
```

Expected: 1st value  "name":"john"
  actual: printing all details from JSON again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FOR-loop you are looping the list using `${item}` as the iterator. `${item}` will always be a dictionary (you currently have one dictionary in your list). Therefore inside of the loop you need to `Get From Dictionary` referencing the current iterator item to fetch the name and ultimately use it as the whole JSON. Example using multiple entries inside of the list:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Trying it out
    &{DICT}=  Create Dictionary  name=john  id=1  add=usa
    &{ANOTHER_DICT}=  Create Dictionary  name=jane  id=2  add=eu
    @{LIST}=  Create List  ${DICT}  ${ANOTHER_DICT}

    ${type_ABC}=     Evaluate    type(@{LIST})
    log to console  ${type_ABC}
    : FOR    ${item}     IN      @{LIST}
    \  ${name}=   Get From Dictionary       ${item}         name
    \  log to console     Name: ${name}
    \  log to console     Actual: ${item}
```

Comment: &{DICT} says definition is not found what to do? I tried some option by setting variables.

Comment: @anj could you update your question to represent the current Robot test file you are using?